# add info for sender in contact form

Tags: php, forms, send

how to add info for user like ip , send time (by conutry like egypt time) , browser , Resolution , vistor come from

this is my php file

```
<?php
$webmaster_mail = 'sales@elfnoon.com';
$redirect_page = 'http://www.elfnoon.com/';
$message_subject = 'رسالة من زائر لموقعك';

$in_Body ='';
    foreach($_POST as $in_k=>$in_v)
    {
$in_Body .="$in_k = $in_v\n\n";
    }
mail(trim($webmaster_mail), "$message_subject ", "$in_Body","From: " . trim($webmaster_mail));
header("Location: $redirect_page");
?>
```

and this form

```
<form action="form.php" method="post">
    <input name="" type="text" value="اسمك الكريم" onblur="if (this.value=='')this.value='اسمك الكريم'" onclick="value=''" />
    <br />
    <input name="email" type="text" value="البريد الالكتروني" />
                        <br />
    <input name="phone" type="text" value="رقم الهاتف" onblur="if (this.value=='')this.value='رقم الهاتف'" onclick="value=''" />
                    <br />
                    <textarea name="msg" cols="41" rows="5" placeholder="نص الرساله" wrap=soft></textarea>
                    <br />
                    <input type="submit" value="ارسال" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

For information about IP and browser you can check `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` and `$_SERVER['USER_AGENT']` (see var_dump($_SERVER) to all available entries).

You can get the time with timezone indication using: `date('Y-m-d e');` the "e" will show the timezone if you're running PHP5.1+ ( http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date.php )

**EDIT**

```
<?php
$webmaster_mail = 'sales@elfnoon.com';
$redirect_page = 'elfnoon.com/';
$message_subject = 'رسالة من زائر لموقعك';
$in_Body ='';
foreach($_POST as $in_k=>$in_v) {
  $in_Body .="$in_k = $in_v\n\n";
}
$in_Body .= 'The sender IP: ' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$in_Body .= 'The sender Browser: ' . $_SERVER['USER_AGENT'];
mail(trim($webmaster_mail), "$message_subject ", "$in_Body","From: " . trim($webmaster_mail));
header("Location: $redirect_page");
?>
```

Comment: where i add $_SERVER['USER_AGENT'] in

<?php
$webmaster_mail = 'sales@elfnoon.com';
$redirect_page = 'http://www.elfnoon.com/';
$message_subject = 'رسالة من زائر لموقعك';

$in_Body ='';
 foreach($_POST as $in_k=>$in_v)
 {
$in_Body .="$in_k = $in_v\n\n ";
 }
mail(trim($webmaster_mail), "$message_subject ", "$in_Body","From: " . trim($webmaster_mail));
header("Location: $redirect_page");
?>

Comment: any idea how to use date("F j, Y, g:i a");
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
$_SERVER['USER_AGENT'] in php file?????

Comment: @C0derMan By learning PHP? I mean come on no offense that is such a simple thing `$f = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`

Comment: please full code
this my php file

<?php
$webmaster_mail = 'sales@elfnoon.com';
$redirect_page = 'http://www.elfnoon.com/';
$message_subject = 'رسالة من زائر لموقعك';
$f = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
$in_Body ='';
 foreach($_POST as $in_k=>$in_v)
 {
$in_Body .="$in_k = $in_v\n\n";
 }
mail(trim($webmaster_mail), "$message_subject ", "$in_Body","From: " . trim($webmaster_mail));
header("Location: $redirect_page");
?>

Comment: @C0derMan come on.. I think you should try a little here. $in_Body held the text message. So, just assign the $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] and the other vars to it. Look at my edit..

Comment: little help here with php please
starting php from 1 month but i stop learn php for this time to learn frist css and html5

so $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] and other vars where i add
forgive me need really help with it

Comment: @C0derMan I think Lucasvscn has actually edited his answer to spoon feed you the knowledge.

Comment: now The sender Browser: dont display what browser use
and how to add <br /> between ever line

Comment: now all ok i fix some

here is code

$in_Body .= 'Time: ' .  gmdate('F j, Y, h:i:s A') . "\n\n";

but if i want make time by country like egypt time??